# Reading from a file and checking individual characters

Tags: file

I'm trying to read a file, character-by-character, store the character in a variable, check if it is a certain value and continue until the entire file has been read.

Here is the code I've gotten so far:

I want the variable i to increment if the character is A (49 ASCII value) but the program prints the following: 0000000000.

Comment: Did you mean int x = 0; or int i = 0;? You need to initialize i to 0 or switch i to x.

Comment: Sorry about that, I wrote the wrong variable in the print statement. I've updated the post to include the correct variable. It is still outputting 0000000000 though which is not what I intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize your counter variable i.

```
FILE * fp;
fp = fopen("doc.txt", "r");
int i = 0; /* switch x to i */

while (!feof(fp)) {

  int fc = fgetc(fp);

  if (fc == 49) {
    i++;  
  }
}
printf("%d", i);
```

Comment: @Chrome123 You are still incrementing i with i++ while printing out x at the end. Choose either x or i and then use that variable consistently throughout your code.

Comment: @Chrome123 Also move your print statement outside the while loop so it does not output until the file reading is finished. How many characters are in your input file. You should have seen output that matched the number of characters in the file given that error.

Comment: @Chrome123 Happy to help.